# Troubleshooting X sudden restart/crash using XFCE 4.8 with stylus pen

Tags: linux, crash, gimp, xfce

I have a convertible laptop/tablet with graphics tablet screen, which often logs out of the current X session whilst using GIMP 2.6. I am dropped back to the login prompt without a system wide restart. All unsaved work is lost, making this a real problem for me.

This only seems to happen whilst reaching over the keyboard to draw on the screen. I have disabled the <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> shortcut so I don't believe leaning on the keyboard is causing the problem.

There is no output to dmesg or xsession-errors when the restart occurs.
Any advice on how to track down or deal with this problem would be appreciated.

OS: Linux mint 13, 64 bit (up to date)
Hardware: unmodified HP Compaq 2710p, (laptop/wacom graphics tablet), no external devices connected.

I have sought an answer at the XFCE forums but with no response after two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem as a result of the 'x' media key (f4) on my lenovo p500. The f4 key is by default an '[x] close' key. Unless I hit fn first.

Anyway, pressing said key on the desktop kills xfce in one keystroke. My current solution is to disable it with xmodmap:

1. Use xev to read the keycode (focus the window and press the media key)
2. Use xmodmap -e 'keycode #=' to disable it, ie: `xmodmap -e 'keycode 64='`